# Input form doesn't work on my tumblr blog

Tags: html, forms, tumblr, mailchimp

I have a website based on tumblr - [here it is](http://veiila.com)

Whatever I tried to embed mailchimp signup form it never worked. It showed only text fields (email address, name etc) but no input form at all.

Finally I found out that input forms do not work on my blog at all. Even when I try to copy/paste some simple absolutely working example from the html cheat sheet or even copy the easiest from from another site (so my mistakes are not involved) I still see only the names of the fields but not the fields.

For example:

If I paste this code on [this page](http://veiila.com/subscribe) (it's a page for experiments)

```
<form> First name:<br> <input type="text" name="firstname"> <br> Last name:<br> <input type="text" name="lastname"> </form>
```

I see only text "First name" and "Last Name" (as you can see on the page). But no input fields. While other html and scripts work pretty well (another submission form made as a script worked perfectly, unfortunately mailchimp doesn't provide this type of forms)

This is real pain in the neck! If anyone can help it'll be really great!

Thanks

Comment: There seem to be a number of possible solutions, search Stack Overflow itself I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8347256/what-html-attributes-are-allowed-on-a-tumblr-post-tinymce

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's possible on an individual "blog" page, but this is how to get it to work on the home page.

On the main "Edit Theme" page, at the very top above "Browse themes" you should see "Edit HTML".

Copy the Mailchimp code sample and paste into a text editor like notepad. The very top of the sample looks like this:

```
<link href="//cdn-images.mailchimp.com/embedcode/classic-081711.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<style type="text/css">
    #mc_embed_signup{background:#fff; clear:left; font:14px Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; }
    /* Add your own MailChimp form style overrides in your site stylesheet or in this style block.
       We recommend moving this block and the preceding CSS link to the HEAD of your HTML file. */
</style>
```

Cut this part of the code and paste it in your HTML of your home page just before the first `<status>` tag.

Then paste the rest of the code in the main body of your HTML. I put mine after the `</header>` tag.

This got the fields to show up where previously they wouldn't, but the "Subscribe" button still wasn't showing.

Towards the bottom of the code there is a line that starts with `<div class="clear">`. Change that to `<div class="show">`

Again, not exactly what I was looking for, but it got me closer to my solution. It may be sufficient for you.

Comment: Your original answer was deleted because (at [revision 1](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/31463156/1) at least) it wasn't an answer, it said no more than "me too". After you edited it the right action to take would be to flag it for undeletion rather than reposting. No harm done though